# Swift 3 NSError expecting call type after?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am adding google sign in to my Xcode project. I am setting up an error configurator so the sign in will work, but it keeps giving me errors when I try to define the error as NSError?. What am I doing wrong?

```
class logInController: UIViewController, GIDSignInUIDelegate {

    func CGRectMake(_ x: CGFloat, _ y: CGFloat, _ width: CGFloat, _ height: CGFloat) -> CGRect {
        return CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: width, height: height)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad(){
        super.viewDidLoad()

        var error = NSError?
        GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&error)

        if error != nil {
            print(error)
            return
        }

        GIDSignIn.sharedInstance().uiDelegate = self

        let signInButton = GIDSignInButton(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 50))
        signInButton.center = view.center
        view.addSubview(signInButton)
    }    
}
```

Xcode says, `"expected member name or constructor call type after name"`, but when I add something like a domain or userInfo it tells me, `"argument labels [] do not match any available overloads"`

Comment: `var error: NSError?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either you declare a type with a constructor

```
var error = NSError(domain:...
```

or as optional pointer

```
var error : NSError?
```

To use the variable as an inout parameter you have to use the latter.

PS: Get used to the Swift 3 changes like `CGRect` passing all parameter labels...