# "Any other keywords? for GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError()"

Tags: swift, google-signin

Cannot convert value of type 'NSError?.Type' to expected argument type 'NSError?'

I created a variable for NSError, but it used to be "var error = NSError?" but it doesn't work i tried to make it "var error = NSError?.self" it doesn't return any error. But when i called it in the "GGLContext.sharedInInstance().configurationWithError(&error)" it gives me an error of "Cannot convert value of type 'NSError?.Type' to expected argument type 'NSError?'" what should i do.

i tried "var error = NSError?.self", "var error = Error.Self"
and called it to the configurationWithError(&error) yet gives me the same error

```
import UIKit
import Google
import GoogleSignIn

class LoginViewController: UIViewController {


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

//        var error = Error?.self
//        GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(error)
        var error = NSError?.self
        GGLContext.sharedInstance().configureWithError(&error)
        let signInButton = GIDSignInButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 100, height: 50))
        signInButton.center = view.center
        view.addSubview(signInButton)
    }



}

//THIS IS THE FULL CODE IN MY VIEWCONTROLLER
```

Cannot convert value of type 'NSError?.Type' to expected argument type 'NSError?'This is the Error.

Comment: A [quick search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+GGLContext.sharedInstance%28%29.configureWithError) shows you the correct syntax.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift 3 NSError expecting call type after?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42382839/swift-3-nserror-expecting-call-type-after)